# "Contains" implementation of ArrayList vs HashSet

Tags: java, collections, equals, contains, hashcode

I have a `HashSet<Foo>`.
I have an object that is

1. equal to an element of the collection and
2. has a matching hashcode to the same object of the implementation.

Still if I call `hashSet.contains(fooInstance)` it returns `false`.

Where it gets really weird is that the following line returns `true`:

```
new ArrayList<Foo>(hashSet).contains(fooInstance)
```

Sadly it turned out harder than expected to find out where exactly is the difference of the `.contains()` implementation.
But I thought I would be safe, since `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` work fine.

Comment: Is the hashCode of `Foo` stable?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Apparently not, that's the only thing that can be causing the OPs stated behavior according to the current description.

Comment: @Thihara Thanks. That already helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the `hashCode` of `Foo` is not stable and that the return value of `hashCode()` of the `Foo` instance changed *after* it was added to the `HashSet`. Ideally, you would only ever add immutable objects to a `HashSet`.

For performance reasons the `HashSet` stores the calculated `hashCode` in its entry, so that it doesn't need to re-calculate it for each `get`. So if the object changes while inside the `HashSet`, this won't be realized and your object will effectively be "lost" in the `HashSet` (you can still get it, by iterating over all elements, which is essentially what copying into an `ArrayList` does).

Comment: This would mean that `contains` uses a different HashSet than the one I am calculating at a later point?
This would explain why I can still find an element in the collection that equals and has the same hashcode, but still isn't "contained".

Comment: @fancy: no, why would that mean that? It just means that at the time you added the `Foo` to the `HashSet` it's `hashCode()` returned a different value from what it returns now (and form what your other object returns). Show us the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations of your `Foo` and we can tell you more.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Doesn't the hashcode also identify the specific hash bucket it is stored in: different hashcode -> looking in wrong bucket, nothing found

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sry, I misspellt. I meant "different haschcode", not HashSet.
Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: yes, that's yet another reason for it not to be found.